# Can I create another entity with only 2 fields to map to the same table

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Here is the table with only 2 fields below:

```
 customer_order_base { cust_id, cust_lookup_fact }
```

This is already mapped to the entity called `CustomerOrderBase` using both fields.  I needed to create a lighter-weight Entity model of several other tables some of which have 40+ fields by using only a subset of the fields in those tables for performance reasons.

These newly created light-weight entities are also pointing to the same database tables as the heavy-weight model.

Unfortunately,  I have now encountered the above table `customer_order_base` which has only has 2 fields. Is it possible to create another entity to map to this table? I only want to use it for reading purposes and joining with other tables.

Without this table, I cannot do the necessary joins that are needed with some of the tables.

```
Is the first case done like this? Using the 2 columns which already exist in the original mapping?

@Immutable
@Entity("DuplicateCustomerOrderBasename=")
@Table("customer_order_base")
public class DuplicateCustomerOrderBase {

  @Id
  @Generator(...)
  BigInteger cust_id;

  @Column(name="cust_fact", insertable="false", updatable="false")
  private String cust_lookup_fact;

}
```

Comment: Are you looking for a builder pattern - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know only two ways to map the same table to different entities:

First:

Map the whole table to an entity. You can map more entities to the same table, but you have to annotate these (small) entities with `org.hibernate.annotations.Immutable`. You cannot modify these small entities.

Second:

Use inheritance with inheritance strategy `InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE`.

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public class Base {

    @Id
    private Long id;
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("SubBase")
public class SubBase1 extends Base {

    private String value1;
}
```

Comment: Does that mean, I can map the table to the same columns in case 1

Comment: You are right. You can use the same column twice or more. But *attention*: You can't modify the data. Any `persist` or `merge` do nothing. Therefor there is no need of `@Generator(...)` cause you cannot persist the immutable entity

Comment: Thank you, very much. Is there anywhere this is documented, I have been unable to find any information about this. I do appreciate your help.

Comment: You are welcome. I don't know, if there is any documentation for this use case - it's the experience after a lot of years ;-)